# Must an IDictionary implementation that implements INotifyPropertyChanged be thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, inotifypropertychanged, concurrentdictionary

I'm looking at [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/116562/1714) for an observable dictionary I want to use with Xamarin.iOS / Android. There are comments and answers that indicate that the concurrency isn't a concern.

Generally speaking, when dealing with an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, what threadsafe guarantees should I rely on?

in other words:

- When using an observable dictionary from the UI thread, must that object also be thread safe?
- What if the Dictionary isn't managed on the UI thread?

I'm considering an alternate implementation

Answer (score 1):

> Generally speaking, when dealing with an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, what threadsafe guarantees should I rely on?

When an object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, its member `PropertyChanged`, which is an event handler for intercepting the property changed action, should be implemented in our code, then we also need to create method/ function to handle this event, thus to make sure multiple threads don't conflict when operate on this object. For example:

```cs
public class Test1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _test;

    public string test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _test)
            {
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is now that how `PropertyChanged` event would keep it safe, if you use `ILSpy` to check the source code of [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), you will find that inside it, it just implements a delegate `PropertyChanged`, and the delegate is like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    /// <summary>Represents the method that will handle the <see cref="E:System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged" /> event raised when a property is changed on a component.</summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event. </param>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs" /> that contains the event data. </param>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    [HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, SharedState = true)]
    public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
}
```

You should be able to find that there is a `HostProtection` attribute above this delegate, this attribute allows the use of declarative security actions to determine host protection requirements. Inside the implementation of this `HostProtectionAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute`, it creates thread synchronization lock. Following is the partial code of it:

```cs
/// <summary>Gets or sets a value indicating whether synchronization is exposed.</summary>
/// <returns>true if synchronization is exposed; otherwise, false. The default is false.</returns>
public bool Synchronization
{
    get
    {
        return (this.m_resources & HostProtectionResource.Synchronization) > HostProtectionResource.None;
    }
    set
    {
        this.m_resources = (value ? (this.m_resources | HostProtectionResource.Synchronization) : (this.m_resources & ~HostProtectionResource.Synchronization));
    }
}

/// <summary>Gets or sets a value indicating whether shared state is exposed.</summary>
/// <returns>true if shared state is exposed; otherwise, false. The default is false.</returns>
public bool SharedState
{
    get
    {
        return (this.m_resources & HostProtectionResource.SharedState) > HostProtectionResource.None;
    }
    set
    {
        this.m_resources = (value ? (this.m_resources | HostProtectionResource.SharedState) : (this.m_resources & ~HostProtectionResource.SharedState));
    }
}
```

So for your question:

> When using an observable dictionary from the UI thread, must that object also be thread safe?
>
> What if the Dictionary isn't managed on the UI thread?

In UI thread, if there is no cross thread variable accessing in your code, it's safe, otherwise, this will cause insecurity. When not in the UI thread, we need to use invoke way (UI Dispatcher) to push the action to UI thread.

Comment: I want to use a dictionary to collect objects sent to me by Bluetooth. I will then scan and cleanup that dictionary using Rx and a timer equivalent. If this isn't in the UI thread, in addition to using a concurrent dictionary, what should I do to maintain safety for the events?

Comment: Is there anything else I should look at for this use case?

Comment: @LamonteCristo, use collection which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface should be safe in any thread, as I said, if it is in other thread and you want to use it in UI thread, you can use UI dispatcher, it's a safe way. But from your description, are you targeting the Bluetooth accessory which is connected to Android device through serial port?

Comment: I'm going to have many different threads that are listening to P2P Wifi, BTLe, Internet Push notifications, and NFC. Platforms are iOS Android and limited WinPhone. All of these will push information to the dictionary with a date stamp. A maintenance thread will summarize and age out/archive data.  For debug purposes, the data will be shown in a TableView